# Keep getting an error for the get() of an arraylist. Why?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm busy making a Java game, and for enemies, I store them in an `ArrayList`. But when I try to use the `get(int)` method, it keeps giving me `The type of get(int) is erroneous where E is a type-variable:` Why is this? Shouldn't it just return the element? I've searched a while and haven't been able to find a solution to this.

Here's the part of my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<holes.size();i++){
    hole temp = holes.get(i);
    if((p1.playerRec.x/48)==(temp.holeRec.x/48) && (p1.playerRec.y/48)==(temp.holeRec.y/48)){
        gameOver=true;
    }
}

public void findHoles(){
    for(int i=0;i<map1.height;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<map1.width;j++){
            if(map1.tileMap[i][j]==5){
                addHole(new hole(i,j));
            }
        }   
    }
}

public void addHole(hole h){
    holes.add(h);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps some code will enlight us!

Comment: You probably should read about [generic types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Comment: I guess because you assign it to different type variable :p

Comment: Here's the part of my code:
http://pastebin.com/ntmxHRCC

Comment: haha, are you used inherited classes??, you can't use the type of the base class to get derived classes intances in a list!

Comment: It's an arraylist of the object holes. I'm trying to see if my player is standing on any of the holes on the map

Comment: um you're casting to (Integer) did you figured that?

Comment: if you are referring to holes, no it doesnt subclass anything

Comment: oh haha forget that its there. I was just putting it there to test something. I still get the error without it

Comment: Delete the cast, is in the post too...

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry about that. The Integer cast wasn't supposed to be there...

Comment: What is the declared type of `holes`?  Show us the declaration.

Comment: How is holes instantiated?, is a problem of types for sure

Comment: @DGomez - it will be the declaration that is the problem, not the instantiation / creation of an instance.

Comment: Alright I edited it to show the instantiation. It just adds a new hole to the list

Comment: Sorry, i tried to say what @StephenC says, the line where you declared the holes list, ArrayList<someType> c = new ....

Comment: well i just have ArrayList<hole> holes = new ArrayList<hole>(); outside of the constructor of this class, which is the game panel

Comment: mmm, can you post the exact stacktrace?

Comment: well I'm writing my code in netbeans and compiling in command prompt and it doesn't give me an error when I compile or run it, it just doesnt function correctly. But netbeans does give me an underlined error.

Comment: Why on earth would you edit code in an IDE and compile elsewhere?? Actually... nevermind... I don't think I even want to know!

Answer (score 4):

Hey generic user2305801,

as much as I have to emphasise using syntax conventions, as Stephen C is insisting on, I'm sure you're code is not causing this specific problem, when you declare class-names lowercase.

I just shot myself an arrow in the knee, by supposedly making the same mistake as you. Although you surely solved the problem in the meantime, I'll mention the possible solution for the records here:

Maybe you're missing a package statement at the top of your file in the external classfile containing the declaration for the hole-class. If the classfile already contains a package declaration then make it the same namespace as the file you're referencing the class from.

So in the referencing file write:

```
package whackamole;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ...
    for(int i=0;i<holes.size();i++){
        Hole temp = holes.get(i);
    }
    ...
}
```

And in the class-file:

```
package whackamole;

public class Hole
{
    ...
}
```

I know the code-example is a bit superfluous, but I just wanted to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is not making a lot of sense based in the information that you have trickle fed us ...

But there is a clue in the code.

You appear to have ignored the Java identifier naming rules and named one of your classes 'hole' instead of 'Hole'.  This is bad style.  But the consequences could be worse than a slap on the wrist from the style police.

The problem is that Java's name resolution rules are designed to work best when you obey the style rules.  If you declare a variable/field 'hole' and you also have a class called 'hole', the JLS says that the variable / field name takes precedence ... in some contexts.  This can lead to some pretty confusing compilation error messages, if you actually meant 'hole' to mean a class.

So ...

Fix the style violation by renaming the class 'hole' to be 'Hole'.  This may also make the weird compilation errors go away.  But you should do it anyway!

Comment: **PLEASE** follow the naming conventions for the sake of everyone's sanity (including the compiler it appears)!!  I don't understand why professors don't make a bigger deal out of style guidelines...

Comment: If it's a beginner course, which it looks like it is, it's not up to the professor, it's up to the TAs. The TAs generally do enforce coding styles, but different ones are more lenient or more strict about it.